# How to calculate the correct zoom factor?

Tags: c#

I have a problem.
I have an image that comes from a camera.
I stretch the image inside a Viewbox which is 877*877 px big.
The camera image can have a resolution fromm 100*100 px to 3000*3000 px.
Right now the complete image is stretched inside the ViewBox with the help of Windows.ScaleTransform.
I also have a zoom function in the software which works correctly. It also works with Windows.ScaleTransform.
It looks like this:
[image]

Now to my problem: The zoom factor has to be 100% (1) when the camera is image is 877*877, but it is always 100% when the zoom is not working.
When the Viewbox show's a stretched 3000x3000 px image the zoom should be 29% and not 100%. 
Any idea how I can manage this?

I am looking forward to an answer.
Greetings
Richard

Comment: At the moment, it's unclear what you are asking. Can't you just set the zoom factor to 29% (or rather: 877/actual_resolution)?

Comment: @Heinzi Without zoom I could use the 877/actual_resolution but when I zoom in the actual_resolution didn't change. It simply changed the pixelsize inside the ViewBox, so the pixel are bigger

Comment: So, set it to 29% initially and then let the user zoom? (Maybe a [mcve] would help to understand your problem.)

Comment: Would recommend using a number divisible by 2 as the dimensions of the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int max = img.width > img.height ? img.width : img.height;
int percent = ViewWindowSize / max * 100;
```

Comment: This works when I don't zoom in. When I zoom, thanks to the windows.ScaleTransform, the ViewWindowSize and the max still have the same size. The pixelsize simply changes. So I also need to addthe Pixelsize or the Zoomfactor to the formula

Comment: Maybe you should explain a bit more what it does and/or why it works?

Comment: Change ViewWindowSize / max to (ViewWindowSize * PixelSize) / max